# SQL - Update a field in the results of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with an `UPDATE` statement where I'd like to update a field in the results of another stored procedure.

First stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_sproc1]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Database1.dbo.tbl_dB1table AS t1
            INNER JOIN Database2.dbo.tbl_dB2table AS t2 ON t1.field = t2.field
            INNER JOIN Database3.dbo.tbl_dB3table AS t3 ON t3.field2 = t1.field2 AND t3.field2 = t2.field2
            INNER JOIN Database4.dbo.tbl_dB4table AS t4 ON t4.field3 = t2.field3
    WHERE       (field5 = 'c') AND (some_date IS NULL)
END
```

Second stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ASCRoadAmericaUpdateDateInternal] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE      Database1.dbo.tbl_dB1table
    SET         spr1.some_date = GETDATE()
    FROM (EXEC dbo.[usp_sproc1]) AS spr1
END
```

So I want to retrieve the result set of the first stored procedure and then updated the some_date field in `Database1.tbl_dB1table` with today's date but only those records which are returned by the first stored procedure.

Is it possible to accomplish this without dumping the results from the first stored procedure into a `CURSOR` and iterating through each record?

Comment: So place the query from the first stored procedure in the ( .. ) in the FROM in the second stored procedure?  My original thought was to make it as OOP as possible by reusing the sproc so that if the first sproc changes there wouldn't be a need to change the second sproc.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code.  I had changed the dB and table names to make it obscure and missed the one on the UPDATE line.  I tried using the WHERE clause from the first sproc in the second sproc but it wants to update more records than the first sproc returns because it is missing the joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_sproc2
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE t1 
    SET some_date = GETDATE() -- you probably mean CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())?
  FROM        Database1.dbo.tbl_dB1table AS t1
  INNER JOIN  Database2.dbo.tbl_dB2table AS t2 
              ON t1.field = t2.field
  INNER JOIN  Database3.dbo.tbl_dB3table AS t3 
              ON t3.field2 = t1.field2 
              AND t3.field2 = t2.field2
  INNER JOIN  Database4.dbo.tbl_dB4table AS t4 
              ON t4.field3 = t2.field3
  WHERE       (field5 = 'c') AND (t1.some_date IS NULL);
  -------------^^^^^^ what table does this column come from?
END
GO
```

Comment: Awsome! Seems like I was waayy over thinking this.  Thanks Aaron.